# graphql filer options do not represent filters data

Tags: filter, graphql

When I query the [test site](https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/graphql) with chomeIQL extension using the query:

```
query category($cat: String) {
  products(filter: {category_id: {eq: $cat}}) {
    filters {
      name
      filter_items {
        label
        value_string
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get filters like:

```
"name": "Fashion Color",
"filter_items": [
  {
    "label": "Gold",
    "value_string": "14",
    "__typename": "LayerFilterItem"
  },
  {
    "label": "Peach",
    "value_string": "18",
    "__typename": "LayerFilterItem"
  },
```

But the graphQl docs (Docs => Query => Producs => filter) is of type ProductFilerInput and that has nothing resembling color.

The data for the price is:

```
    {
        "name": "Price",
        "filter_items": [
        {
            "label": "<span class=\"price\">$0.00</span> - <span class=\"price\">$99.99</span>",
            "value_string": "-100",
            "__typename": "LayerFilterItem"
        },
        {
            "label": "<span class=\"price\">$100.00</span> and above",
            "value_string": "100-",
            "__typename": "LayerFilterItem"
        }
        ]
    }
```

How does that represent ProductFilterInput.price which is FilterTypeInput (`{gt:String,lt:String ...}`?

Is this caused by settings not being correct or is it a thing with Magento graphql not fully compatible with the rest of the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because [graphql part is not hooked up to configurable product.](https://github.com/magento/graphql-ce/issues/500)

> > what about filtering for things such as Fashion Material or size, etc? Those attributes are part of ConfigurableProduct but I wasn't able to filter for them. See magento/pwa-studio#1432